# Apache Tomcat v7.0 is deleting images uploaded when reinitialized

Tags: image, apache, tomcat

I am developing an web application which uploads images to an Apache Tomcat server. The problem is whenever I make changes on my server, it is reinitialized and the images loaded before, are deleted from my images folder on Server.

I would like to know if there is any configuration I can make to maintain these files when the server is reinitialized.

I'm running it on localhost:8080 and the version is Apache Tomcat v7.0. I'm also developing it on Eclipse IDE.

Comment: It sounds like you are creating the image folder in a temporary directory, or within the (deployed) app folder. Neither of which is viable for permanent storage.

Comment: hmm.. maybe I am. I will change my storage directory

Comment: Always store uploaded files outside the webapps directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has basically been given in the comments, here with a bit more reasoning:

Always store uploaded data in a separate directory, outside of your webapplication.

One of the reasons is exactly what you discovered: Updates or redeployments of your application will delete the data otherwise. Doing backups is quite hard. In fact, I'd advice against having the webapp directory writeable to tomcat at all, to mitigate this and the next issues:

Another issue is that you're opening yourself to implicit server-side code injection: Imagine someone uploading a jsp to your webapplication: This can contain arbitrary code that would silently be executed unless you thought about filtering this kind of content (nobody does, and nobody runs tomcat in a security manager / Sandbox. Of course this is a simplification)

Further, when you dynamically update your webapp data, you cannot tell what data has been uploaded after deployment, so that you can't easily bring updates back into your code base if they're uploaded later: You'll basically have to identify changes.

And finally, you cannot even assume that tomcat always unpacks a war file - there's a setting that makes tomcat serve applications directly from war files, without unzipping them to webapps. If you don't administer the server yourself, change the platform to something else or if tomcat's default configuration changes to this in future, you might end up puzzled.